# Explanation of difference between $P(A\mid B)$ and $ P(A \cap B)$

Tags: probability

I know that $(A \cap B) = P(A\mid B)\times P(B)$ or other wise. But my question is, if $P(A\mid B)$ is the probability of $A$ happening given $B$,and $P(A \cap B)$ is the probability of $A$ and $B$ happening together, why not $P(A\mid B)= P(A \cap B)$ ?

Comment: Because P(A/B) assumes B is true.  i.e. it is dividing P(A and B) by P(B).

Comment: I'm sorry but I still don't get it.It assumes B is true?So P(A intersection B) assumes B is not true?What does it have to do with T/F here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because P($A \cap B $) is based off of the possibility that $B $ might not happen.

P($A|B $) ignores $A \land \lnot B $ situations.  It assumes $B$ has occurred and thus removes all $\lnot B $

Comment: Much better explanation.Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I also figured it another way; thought I would share it as well.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rRhh.jpg)